# Multiple section breaks - how to add header and footer only to 1st section?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I wrote a code which adds header and footer to the document. The document has multiple sections (page breaks) and I want only to add the header and footer to the 1st page.
In the code I have selected section (1), but macro is adding header and footer to 1st page of each section.

Do you know how to fix it? I tried and have no idea. Code below:

```
With wordApp.ActiveDocument
    .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    .Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage) _
    .Range.InsertBefore _
    Cells(18, i)
End With

With wordApp.ActiveDocument
    .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage) _
    .Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(15, i)
End With
```

Comment: Does this code run from Excel? If yes are you using late binding or early binding? Do you use `Option Explicit`? Have you set a reference (Menu Extras > References) to Microsoft Word? • If you are not sure about the answers to the questions I asked, what is the result of the following code in the immediate window `Debug.Print CLng(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)`?

Comment: Yes, the code runs from excel. 

I am just starting with VBA, so I am not sure, but I didn't declare any variables for this particular section of the code. 

The result for the code you gave is '2'.

Comment: You will need to edit section 2 and remove the "SameAsPrevious" flag. Not sure how in VBA, but basically section 2 copies section 1 until you remove that flag. So, your issue is not your code, it is what is missing from editing section 2

Comment: The link to previous setting needs to be set **six times** in *each section*, or at least the section after you are adding the header/footer. This setting is for each of the three headers and three footers in each section after the first. **This needs to be done before you add anything to the header/footer"** See my recap of header and footer settings: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings  http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#LinkPrevious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should need is:

```
With wordApp.ActiveDocument
  .Sections(1).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
  .Sections(2).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
  With .Sections(1)
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text = Cells(15, i)
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.InsertBefore Cells(18, i)
  End With
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I only had to add shapes to header, as I wanted to add it on specific side of the page, but all sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we need to address your incorrect use of terminology. Page Breaks only add new pages, they do **not** create sections. It is Section Breaks that create new sections.

By default the headers and footers in new sections are linked to the previous section. You can see this on the Header & Footer tab when you edit a header or footer in one of the later sections.
[image]

You can remove the link by using the following code, which is pretty old and dates back to when Link to Previous was called Same as Previous

```
Public Sub ZapTheSAP()
   Dim sec As Section
   Dim hdrftr As HeaderFooter

   For Each sec In ActiveDocument.Sections
      For Each hdrftr In sec.Headers
         hdrftr.LinkToPrevious = False
      Next hdrftr

      For Each hdrftr In sec.Footers
         hdrftr.LinkToPrevious = False
      Next hdrftr
   Next sec
End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry, these are section breaks indeed. I have deleted these links to previous already. 

It looks more that my code treats each section as a new document and adds the same stuff all over again. Even after selectin in code ''Sections(1)'' .

Comment: @AdamZiaja - Setting `LinkToPrevious = False` simply removes the link and leaves the content, which you can then delete as necessary.

Comment: Tried sections.first.pagesetup.DifferentFirstPage?

Comment: I have so maybe you could explain your understanding.  AFAIK differentfi4stpage on activedocument sets all sections. My suggestion only the first so page 1 of the document

Comment: @AdamZiaja - Section Breaks should only be used when there is a change in page layout. Are you sure that the document actually needs to have multiple sections?